# rowCount with signal of QTablewidget at startup

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots, qtablewidget

Having two classes, first class `Table` with QTableWidget with a function to invoke signal at startup with custom signal and slot to count numbers of rows.

Custom signal uses to emit and transform numbers of rows to another class.

First part is working as expected. It seems slots never emits or invokes the function within another class.

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    rowCount = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.countrow()

    def countrow(self):
        count = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.rowCount.emit(count)
```

**Another class:**

```
class Anotherwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Anotherwidget, self).__init__()

        self.table = Table()
        self.table.rowCount.connect(self.addrow)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int) 
    def addrow(self, count):
        print(count)
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the signal is emitted before making the connection.

One possible solution is to use `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)`:

```py
class Table(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    rowCount = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.countrow)

    def countrow(self):
        # ...
```

Another possible option is to call countrow after the connection:

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    rowCount = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)

    def countrow(self):
        # ...
```

```
class Anotherwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Anotherwidget, self).__init__()

        self.table = Table()
        self.table.rowCount.connect(self.addrow)
        self.table.countrow()

    def addrow(self):
        # ...
```